# bootstrap Carousel disappears when its looping

Tags: jquery, css, html

hellow everyone, the slider is working good , but when it comes to the last image and want to go back to the first image , it disappears .

here is the bootstrap code  , i didn't use jquery yet

```html
 
        <div id="myslide" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators النقاط المدوره-->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myslide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myslide" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myslide" data-slide-to="2"></li>
       <li data-target="#myslide" data-slide-to="3"></li>

      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
          
         <div class="item">
          <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
          
      <div class="item">
          <img src="images/03.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
     </div>
          
        <div class="item">
          <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myslide" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myslide" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
</div>
```

here is it , when the slider disappears
[image]

Comment: sorry  , can you explain

Comment: See [mcve]. And add a link to http://jsfiddle.net after adding and saving your code.

Comment: You have to have some kind of `JavaScript` code to enable your slider to work. so please as @AllDani suggested. please create a Jsfiddle and update your post and add the link of the Jsfiddle so we can see the problem.